# Changing font for part of text in python-pptx

Tags: python, powerpoint

I'm using the python-pptx module to create presentations. 
How can I change the font properties only for a part of the text?

**I currently change the font like this:**

```
# first create text for shape
ft = pres.slides[0].shapes[0].text_frame
ft.clear()
p = ft.paragraphs[0]
run = p.add_run()
run.text = "text"

# change font
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
from pptx.util import Pt

font = run.font
font.name = 'Lato'
font.size = Pt(32)
font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 255, 255)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PowerPoint, font properties are applied to a *run*. In a way, it is what defines a run; a "run" of text sharing the same font treatment, including typeface, size, color, bold/italic, etc.

So to make two bits of text look differently, you need to make them separate runs.

Comment: Can there be an example of how this would look?

Answer (score 1):

As @scanny says in another post. [The post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59032019/python-pptx-part-of-text-in-cell-with-different-color)

By "different run", it means you should write the text in first color in a run, then afterwards, write the text in the second color in another run as shown below.

There's also an example in the post, I'll just copy and paste it to here

```
from docx.shared import RGBColor
# ---reuse existing default single paragraph in cell---

paragraph = cell.paragraphs[0]

###(First run)
#---add distinct runs of text one after the other to
# --- form paragraph contents.
paragraph.add_run("A sentence with a ")

###(Second run)
# ---colorize the run with "red" in it. 
red_run = paragraph.add_run("red")
red_run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)


###(Third run)
paragraph.add_run(" word.")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).