# Python pptx - part of text in cell with different color

Tags: python, powerpoint, cell, python-pptx

I am using pptx module to generate slide with table. I am able to change font in each cell, but what I also need is change font of specific word in text. In example "Generating **random** sentence as example". In this world "random" is bold.

Found similar case at [text color in python-pptx module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729098/text-color-in-python-pptx-module) ,but that one works with "text frame" and not with cell.

Any advices/suggestions are welcomed!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `cell` where that example uses `text_frame` (or perhaps `tf` in that particular example) the rest of the code is the same. So to create "A sentence with a **red** word" where "red" appears in red color:

```
from docx.shared import RGBColor

# ---reuse existing default single paragraph in cell---
paragraph = cell.paragraphs[0]

# ---add distinct runs of text one after the other to
# --- form paragraph contents
paragraph.add_run("A sentence with a ")

# ---colorize the run with "red" in it---
red_run = paragraph.add_run("red")
red_run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)

paragraph.add_run(" word.")
```

You can find additional details in the documentation here:
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html#font-color

Comment: Yep it's working when I am using text_frame in cell. Thank you!